# Georeferencing system of rivers using XY To Line tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line, polyline-creation

I have a State Water Hydro layer from our GIS county office that does not have georeferenced attributes (It is sitting on top of a State Plane county basemap). Looking at the XY to Line tool I need Start/End XY fields to run the tool. Problem is that there are no such attributes, and I'm looking at an entire county's worth of streams & rivers. Is there a way to determine these XY values without manually going through every stream feature? Also, I'm trying to suggest to my department why having all of our dept. specific features georeferenced is useful for future analysis, but I'm a bit green in the when it comes to justifying the ends to some of our work. Any suggestions on top of the XY to Line tool help would be great.

Comment: Is the data currently stored as points, or lines, or just coordinates? XY to Line will just connect two points, and unless you have unusually straight hydrological features, doesn't seem like it would work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Georeference traditionally means taking a non-spatial raster that does and referencing it to a spatial locations.  Is your river layer in a point or polyline geometry?

Comment: They are all polylines. Is there a way to make the polyline register its XY data all along the line feature?

Comment: Please edit original question with answers. Perhaps by georeference attributes you mean the prj file is not present? are these shape files? If they are polylines and they are aligned with other data of any type. Then they either have a georeference (CRS) or the document's (mxd) reference is implied to the data with no reference. And so you can infer and simply set the crs of the data in question to the same as the document. Tight click on dataframe (usually named layers) and hit properties>coordinate system.

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I would go about it to have XY for each verticies:

1. Use the [Features Verticies to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Feature_Vertices_To_Points/00170000003p000000/) tool (requires Advance license) to generate a point feature class.
2. Use [Add XY Coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_XY_Coordinates/001700000032000000/) tool to display the coordinates for point feature class.
3. Either establish a [relationship](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Deciding_between_relationship_classes_joins_and_relates/004t00000002000000/) between the line and point feature classes; or use the [Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Linear_Referencing_toolbox/003m00000002000000/) tools to create routes and use the point feature class to record event along the line

Comment: -1 as that's a pretty inefficient way which would require an advanced license and ArcMap >= 10.2.1. OP only has 10.1

Comment: @Paul, I don't understand... Feature Verticies to Points and Add XY Coordinates tools are both available at 10.1

Comment: However, Add Geometry Attributes is only available on v10.2.,  question was tagged as v10.1.

Comment: @artwork21 fair enough, I've removed the Add Geometry Attributes tool from my answer.